# Counting number of nested elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, count, size, nested

I want to konw how can I count the child elements under a given Jquery object. I know that 'length' and 'size()' returns the amount of children elements, but I need a function that also count the children's children and so on. So if their is a 'span' tag, nested inside another 'span' and another 'span', the function should return 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a specific element type:

```
$('#my_element').find('span').length
```

For all elements with a specific class:

```
$('#my_element').find('.my_class').length
```

For all elements inside an element:

```
$('#my_element').find('*').length
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/whxf2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$([selector]).find('*')` to get all children of the element.